# Выводится ссылка массива вместо его содержимого

Tags: c++

При вызове объекта выводится адрес массива вместо его содержимого

```
Basket () {
string *ptr ;
string orderArray[7] = {"1.Маргарита ", "2.Пепперони ", "3.Рыбная ",
"4. Четыре сыра ","5.Кальцоне ", "6.Неаполитанская ", "7.Римская"};
cout << orderArray;
ptr = &orderArray[7];
}
```

Comment: А что, по вашему, должно быть выведено? Вы передаете *массив*, получаете адрес... Чтобы вывести все *элементы* массива, надо писать свой цикл. Ну вот представим, что есть такой оператор вывода всего массива... Как в нем должны разделяться элементы? Пробелами? Запятыми? С новой строки? что именно вы ожидали?...

Comment: `cout << orderArray;` вызывается единственная подходящая перегрузка - для указателя на void (в который неявно создается из указателя на первый элемент массива), перегрузок для вывода массива нет

Comment: Да, цикл написал и вывел, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

В имени массива хранится адрес первого элемента массива. Потому выводится адрес первого элемента. Если разыменовать имя массива получим первый элемент массива. Для получения последующих элементов массива необходимо использовать адресную арифметику для продвижения по массиву. И разыменовывание адресов для получения хранящихся в массиве значений.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


void Basket ();


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Basket ();

    return 0;
}


void Basket ()
{
    std::string *ptr ;
    std::string orderArray[7] = {"1.Маргарита ", "2.Пепперони ", "3.Рыбная ",
"4. Четыре сыра ","5.Кальцоне ", "6.Неаполитанская ", "7.Римская"};
    for (auto item : orderArray)
    {
        std::cout << item << std::endl;
    }

    ptr = &orderArray[7];
}
```

Comment: *"В имени массива хранится адрес первого элемента массива."* - нет

Comment: `«Зная имя но не зная размер массива Вы знаете только о адресе первого элемента, а не о всем массиве.»` Ну, с помощью оператора `sizeof` можно легко [узнать](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6ec6e6c077c2d50) количество элементов в массиве: `sizeof(orderArray) / sizeof(orderArray[0])`. Будь имя массива обычным указателем, такой трюк не сработал бы.

Comment: _«Вы считаете что указатель на массив `int-ов` чем-то отличается от указателя на `int`?»_ Да, я так считаю. Массив из десяти элементов типа `int` имеет тип `int [10]`. Указатель на элемент массива имеет тип `int *`. Указатель на массив из десяти элементов типа `int` имеет тип `int (*)[10]`. Это три разных типа.

Comment: @wololo, Andrei прав. Во всем. Ваше `sizeof(orderArray) / sizeof(orderArray[0])` работает только во время компиляции, потому что **толко компиллятор** знает длины переменных. `sizeof` не функция языка, а компилятора.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142105/discussion-on-answer-by-andrei------).

Comment: @MarianD, может разочарую, но типы вообще знает только компилятор. В рантайме их по сути нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понимаю, почему вы именно мне пишете, что типы вообще знает только компилятор. Разве я сказал что-то другое?